# How can I handle reaching voicemail using Twilio's <dial> verb

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-php

I know that on making a call Twilio can detect an answering machine, and react differently.

However if I use the `<dial>` verb, there's no obvious place to add this feature, even though it's essentially the same thing.

My intended flow is:

- Customer enters their phone number
- Twilio calls Customer and plays a voice message
- Twilio dials an agent number, likely a mobile
- If the Agent picks up, connect the customer to the agent
- If the Agent busies the call or does not answer, call will likely go to Agent's voicemail.

  - Terminate call to Agent
  - Record voicemail from Customer
  - Email voicemail to Agent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#examples-1) on the `<Dial>` verb *(emphasis mine)*:

> *This is the simplest case for Dial. Twilio will dial 415-123-4567. If someone answers, Twilio will connect the caller to the called party. If the caller hangs up, the Twilio session ends. **If the line is busy, if there is no answer, or if the called party hangs up**, `<Dial>` exits and the `<Say>` verb is executed for the caller before the call flow ends.*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/simple_dial.xml -->
<Response>
    <Dial>415-123-4567</Dial>
    <Say>Goodbye</Say>
</Response>
```

---

Placing a `<Record>` verb after the `<Say>` verb sounds like what you are looking for.  You can change the timeout from the default value of 30s like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial timeout="9001">415-123-4567</Dial>
    <Say>Please leave a message</Say>
    <Record action="/process_new_voicemail" />
</Response>
```

Comment: That would work if the line is busy or if the person hangs up. Unfortunately it won't work if a voicemail answers; unless the caller gets to the end of the voicemail and causes it to hang up the call. However thanks for the research on this.

Comment: @M1ke I'm not quite sure what you mean by "if a voicemail answers".  The timeout on the `<Dial>` verb should cause the Call to continue to the `<Say>` and `<Record>` verbs if there is no answer from the `<Dial>`.  Is this not what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you mean that the Agent's likely mobile phone has a voicemail box that answers the Call, that is a bit outside the scope of Twilio since the Call is connected to the Agent's mobile carrier instead of Twilio.  You can set the timeout shorter than the voicemail ring time, but if the Agent's phone is off you don't have many options.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is late, but hopefully it helps some one out. It sounds like you may just need to screen the call. 
Basically, you can ask the "agent" that you dialed to accept the call and hang up if you do not receive input.

I am not sure what language you are using, but here is a great php/Laravel tutorial to explain:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/php/laravel

The key part is here:

```
$dialCommand = $response->dial(
    ['action' => route('agent-voicemail', ['agent' => $agent->id], false),
     'method' => 'POST']
);
$dialCommand->number(
    $numberToDial,
    ['url' => route('screen-call', [], false)]
);
```

Notice that the dial command uses the 'action' to specify a location that is sent a POST request should the call end i.e POST to /agent-voicemail.

Then, the number is dialed along with a 'url' parameter **this is the location that will be requested after the agent has picked up but before connecting the two parties.**

The /screen-call route then asks the agent to accept the call, if no input is received it hangs up and will make a POST request to the initial setup /agent-voicemail route.

This method will handle your scenario because if it goes to voicemail no input will be received and the call will end.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution called [human detection](https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-mail-human-detection-studio-functions) where you have the agent press a key to accept the call.

1. Using the [`url`  attribute on <Number>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url), send a `<Gather>` verb to the agent before the call connects.
2. If the agent's voicemail answers, the `<Gather>` will timeout, at which point you can send a `<Hangup>` verb to terminate the call on the agent side.
3. In your `<Dial>` verb's `action` callback, initiate your Twilio-based voicemail flow if `$_POST['DialCallStatus'] == 'completed' && !array_key_exists('DialCallDuration', $_POST)` as this indicates the scenario in #2 where the agent's voicemail answered and the call was ended before the caller was even connected.