# How to Receive and Send voicemail from/on Twilio number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I am creating a Twilio based application that will receive the Voicemail if the call is not picked up.

For now, I had set up the incoming call URL in the console against the phone number.

```
<?php
    header('content-type: text/xml');
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";        
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    file_put_contents('incoming_call.log', "\n" .json_encode($_REQUEST) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>

<Response>
    <Dial timeout="15" action="/voicemail.php">          
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Whereas my voicemail.php file will has to code

```
<?php
// echo "hello ";exit;
    header('content-type: text/xml');
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";

    file_put_contents('incoming_voicemail.log', "\n" .json_encode($_REQUEST) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
<Response>
  <Say voice="alice">Your call could not be answered at the moment. Please leave a voice message. 
  </Say>
  <Record></Record>
</Response>
```

I am not receiving the voicemail. Where can I setup the `recordingStatusCallback attribute` in twiml?

Secondly, I am trying to send voicemail from Twilio number to phone number by dialing One calling and again dial a Second call as the second call will receive a busy status and we are able to send a voicemail, but it's not working. My code is

```
$call = $twilio->account->calls->create(                
    $phone_no, // To
    $from_no, // From
    array(
        "method" => "GET",
         "statusCallback" => SURL . "voicemail?to_phone_no=" . $phone_no,
          "statusCallbackEvent" => ["initiated","ringing"],
          "statusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
          "twiml" => '<Response><Say>Testing voicemail</Say></Response>'
      )
    );
    sleep(3);
    $call2 = $twilio->account->calls->create(
        $phone_no, // To
        $from_no, // From
        array(
            "url" => AURL.'Vm/audio_file'
        )
    );
```

Please guide me what I am doing wrong. For help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

For your first question, if you don't include a [number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) (or a [SIP address](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip), or a [Client identity](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client)) to try to connect to, then the `<Dial>` will move straight on to the `action` URL, without bothering with the `timeout`.

If you want the `<Dial>` to try to connect to a phone, then you should add a phone number.

Second, if you want to receive a webhook when the recording is complete, then you need to add [the `recordingStatusCallback` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback), with a URL to send the webhook to, to your `<Record>`, e.g.:

```
<Response>
  <Say voice="alice">Your call could not be answered at the moment. Please leave a voice message. 
  </Say>
  <Record recordingStatusCallback="/recording-complete.php"></Record>
</Response>
```

Finally, we do not support the final use case of trying to dial a number twice in order to block it up and then leave a voicemail. [Making calls and then dropping them is against the terms of service](https://www.twilio.com/legal/services-documentation) (see point 19 under "prohibited services". So I encourage you to consider a different way to reach out to your customers or contacts that engages with them in a legitimate way.

Comment: what I will receive in `recording-complete.php` the audio file URL ?

Comment: So, for the second question, we can not drop voicemail you said? Just to confirm that the logic for voicemail drop will work or not? I know it's not according to the law for some countries.

Comment: The parameters you receive for a recording status callback are listed here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#recordingstatuscallback.

Comment: For your second question, you can leave voicemail on a user’s phone if they don’t answer, you just can’t make and drop calls in order to try and make a phone go straight to voicemail. It doesn’t matter whether it works or not, it’s against the Twilio terms.

Comment: thank you so much for sharing your knowledge. You saved my day.

Comment: The parameters listed don't have a .mp3 file URL. How can I get the recording file and show it on my server listing page?

Comment: The parameters do have a `RecordingUrl` listed though. [That gives you a WAV file, or if you add `.mp3` to the URL you get an mp3 file](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#fetch-a-recording-media-file).

Comment: Firstly, How can I filter only RecordVerb recordings `$recordings = $twilio->recordings->read([], 200);`
Secondly, Can we decrease the ringing time on users' phones and send voicemails??

Comment: You can’t filter by the method of recording I’m afraid, only by [date created, call SID or conference SID](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#read-multiple-recording-resources). Secondly, you cannot control an end user’s voicemail settings. There is not a legitimate way to specifically leave a voicemail without a phone ringing. You should consider another way to engage with your users.

Comment: How can we send audio recording received in `recording-complete.php ` to a phone number? @philnash @NomanJaved

Comment: @SahilGulati You can play recorded files to phone calls using [TwiML <Play>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play).

Comment: On an outgoing call to a number, I can play the recording, 
But how and when will a User listen to his voicemail which I have recorded for them, to send. @philnash

Comment: @SahilGulati this sounds like more of a new question than a comment. Can you ask a new question, explain what you’ve tried, including code, and then tag me here?